# EC2 server with a crond-service and full /var/spool/exim/-folder

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, amazon-ec2, cron

I'm no expert in linux, apache, etc. but I have this service running on an AWS EC2-server. There is a large number of cron-jobs running on my platform (about 50K / day).

Last week upgraded the EC2-instance and then I started the cron-service on the new instance. Since then, the cron-jobs are leaving a massive amount of output-files in the /var/spool/exim/input-folder. They are all named something like "1mUsgr-0001Ia-DK-H" or "1mUshi-0001PS-Jq-D" and contains the output for a specific cron job. This lead to more than 100GB of these files in a few days and for obvious reasons I don't want that.

So how do I disable this "log" feature for the crond or how do I debug what's causing this?

I don't know what `exim` is but I ran the command `service exim stop` earlier without any luck...

Comment: What Linux distribution is this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after hours of research.

The issue is quite simple. Crontabs are designed to place the output of the cronjob somewhere. Since this destination was not specified in my setup the destination for the output was placed in the `/var/spool/exim/input`-folder with one individual file per output which quickly lead to a huge amount of files and memory issues.

My solution was to specify another "destination" for the output. By adding

```
MAILTO=""
```

to the top of my crontabs, I specify the output to be sent to the email-address "". Now, the `/var/spool/exim/input`-folder is clean and the cronjobs are still running perfectly fine.

If you are reading this, chances are that you could use this solution as well :-)